# Why is the Regex not working?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, youtube

I wrote a Regex to pull a time stamp off a Youtube video and I tested it in Regex101 where it seemed to work, but when I use it in Python i get strange outputs.

The regex is

```
 t=(h?)\d*(m?)\d*(s?)\d*
```

The line where I use the regex is

```
time = re.search("(t=(h?)\d*(m?)\d*(s?)\d*)", s).groups()[0]
```

The input is

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZOGSMUIta_o&feature=share&t=7h18m42s
```

The output is

```
t=7
```

The expected output is

```
t=7h18m42s
```

[Here is where I tested the expression.](http://regex101.com/r/sE4eF4)

I am still very new to programming so any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You simply forgot a "\d*" between "=" and "h".

Comment: Please note that it would make more sense to include the digits that go with "h", "m" or "s" in the same optional group (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

the string that you tested on regex101 is this one:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TrSs453rRr8#t=h219m1551s515
```

the string that you're testing with python is different:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZOGSMUIta_o&feature=share&t=7h18m42s
```

your regex  t=(h?)\d*(m?)\d*(s?)\d* return t=7 because it expects that the first char after h to b "m" and the "h" should appear after the "=", but you have t=7h18m42s so you can't have an "h" after a number. You can try these change your regex to

```
t=\d*(h?)\d*(m?)\d*(s?)\d*
```

or as you're working with an url.

```
t=[^&]
```

Answer (score -1):

You want to use something like this.

```
match = re.search(r"t=(?:\d+h)?(?:\d+m)?(?:\d+s)?", subject)
if match:
    result = match.group()
else:
    result = ""
```

Note that the expressions in parentheses start with a `?:`. This is not indispensable but means that we don't need to capture the contents.

Also, I am not sure exactly how each of these YouTube strings is built, but presumably if the "h" is optional, so should the digits preceding it. This is why each of the time components has been isolated in its own non-capturing group and be made optional.

Comment: I would be really interested to know why someone downvoted this answer. It is more correct than the upvoted one.